# Создать fork на bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Сегодня узнал что с проектом можно работать через fork, начал вникать и что то не заходит, подскажите как можно создать fork проекта на bitbucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбираете в левой панели плюсик:

[image]

А потом выбираете `Fork this repository`:

[image]